# Как обновить страничку после удаления с помощью чекбоксов

Tags: javascript, java, html, mvc, thymeleaf

Я обрабатываю checkboxs с помощью JS, и отправляю данные в контроллер

```
<form>
<table id="tasks"
        border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="10">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><b>Title</b></td>
       <!-- <td><b>Actions</b></td>-->
    </tr>


    <tr data-th-each="task : ${tasks}">

        <td><input type="checkbox" th:id="${task.getId().toString()}" name="task_checkbox"></td>

        <td > <a th:href="@{'/tasksJournal/'+${journalId}+'/updateTask/'+ ${task.getId().toString()}}" data-th-text="${task.getTitle()}"> </a></td>

     <!--   <td>
            <form th:action="@{'/tasksJournal/'+${journalId}+'/deleteTask/'+ ${task.getId().toString()}}" method="post">
                <script>
                    function clickHandler() {
                        window.confirm("Do you really want to delete task?");
                    }
                </script>
                <button type="submit" value="delete" onclick="clickHandler()"/>
                Delete</button>
            </form>
        </td>-->
    </tr>
</table>
<section>
    <h1></h1>
</section>
<div>


        <script th:inline="javascript">
            function getCheckedTasks(journal_id) {
               let result = new Array();
               let checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("task_checkbox");
               for(let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; ++i){
                   if(checkboxes[i].checked === true){
                       result.push(checkboxes.item(i).getAttribute("id"));
                   }
               }
               let resultStr = result[0];
               for(let i = 1; i< result.length; ++i){
                   resultStr = resultStr.concat(',',result[i]);
               }
               let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
               let endpoint = "/tasksJournal/"+ journal_id + "/deleteTasks/";
               xhr.open("POST", endpoint);
               xhr.send(resultStr);
            }
        </script>
        <button value="Delete" style="float:left; margin-right: 2px" th:onclick="getCheckedTasks([[${journalId}]])"/>
        Delete Tasks</button>

</div>

</form>
```

Контроллер

```
   @PostMapping(Endpoints.DELETE_TASKS)
    public String deleteTasks(@PathVariable(name = PathVariables.JOURNAL_ID) String idJournal,
                                  @RequestBody String ids,
                                  Model model) {
        String[] stringIds = ids.split(",");

        for (String currentId : stringIds) {
            try {
                taskService.deleteTaskById(UUID.fromString(currentId));
            } catch (DeleteTaskException e) {
                model.addAttribute(ModelAttributes.NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE, e.getMessage());
                return ErrorPages.NOT_FOUND;
            }
        }
        return String.format(PathTemplates.REDIRECT_TO_HOME, idJournal);
    }
```

После нажатия кнопки Delete Task, таски удаляются успешно, однако во вьюхе, удаленные таски исчезают, только после обновления страницы.
Как сделать так, чтобы выбранные таски с помощью чекбоксов, после нажатия на кнопку Delete Task, сразу исчезали во вьюхе, а не после обновления страницы пользователем?

Comment: Так тебе нужно после удаления таски возвратить те которые остались в бд и заново отрисовать

Comment: Зачем такие сложности? Вы же знаете `id` удаляемых тасков из атрибута `checkbox` - ну так после того как сервер дат положительный ответ о удалении таска - удаляйте `checkbox` с таким `id` из `DOM` страницы.